# (Java, Jackson) How to map a json not having field name to a class with a field of given type

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a json string like this:

```
{
"a": ["cat", "dog"],
"b" : ["jaguar"],
"c": ["sparrow", "penguin"]
}
```

and I want to map it to a model as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String, List<String>> someField;
}
```

How can I map given JSON to the given class?
I am not able to do so because my json is not of the type:

```
{
"someField" : {
"a": ["cat", "dog"],
"b" : ["jaguar"],
"c": ["sparrow", "penguin"]
   }
}
```

i.e. it does not contain the field name.

Is there any way other than writing a custom deserializer?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new JSON object with key as `someField` and value as the JSON object string. Then you can convert this new object to a string and then map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible without much work. Looking at [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map#2-mapltobject-stringgt-deserialization), we create our class like this:

```
@Data
class MyClass {
    private Map<String, List<String>> someField;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyClass(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        this.someField = map;
    }

}
```

And then we read the JSON like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass readValue = mapper.readValue("{\n" + "\"a\": [\"cat\", \"dog\"],\n"
        + "\"b\" : [\"jaguar\"],\n" + "\"c\": [\"sparrow\", \"penguin\"]\n" + "}",
        MyClass.class);
System.out.println(readValue);
```

and receive an output like this:

```
MyClass(someField={a=[cat, dog], b=[jaguar], c=[sparrow, penguin]})
```

The key is `@JsonCreator` in the custom constructor, which tells Jackson to convert the JSON to the specified type (`Map<String, List<String>>`) and build an instance from using that type as parameter for the constructor